# Count of unique lines based on first field in file

Tags: sed, awk, uniq

I am trying to get a count of unique lines output to a file based on the first
field, where the input lines look like:

```
Forms.js     /forms/Forms.js     http://www.gumby.com/test.htm   404
Forms.js     /forms/Forms1.js    http://www.gumby.com/test.htm   404
Forms.js     /forms/Forms2.js    http://www.gumby.com/test.htm   404
Interpret.js     /forms/Interpret1.js    http://www.gumby.com/test.htm   404    
Interpret.js     /forms/Interpret2.js    http://www.gumby.com/test.htm   404
Interpret.js     /forms/Interpret3.js    http://www.gumby.com/test.htm   404
```

To something like this:

```
3    Forms.js    /forms/Forms.js     http://www.gumby.com.mx/test.htm 404
3    Interpret.js    /forms/Interpret.js    http://www.gumby.com.mx/test.htm  404
```

I have been trying various combinations of sort and uniq, but haven't hit on it yet.
I can get distinct lines using the whole line, but I just want the first field.
I am currently using cygwin.  I am not awk literate, but I 
suspect that is the route to go.  Anyone have a handy solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
<infile awk '{ h[$1]++ } END { for(k in h) print h[k], k }'
```

Will get you:

```
3 Forms.js
3 Interpret.js
```

If you also want to keep the first hit use:

```
awk '!h[$1] { g[$1]=$0 } { h[$1]++ } END { for(k in g) print h[k], g[k] }'
```

Output:

```
3 Forms.js /forms/Forms.js http://www.gumby.com/test.htm 404
3 Interpret.js /forms/Interpret1.js http://www.gumby.com/test.htm 404
```

Tested with GNU awk.

Note that this does not require input to be sorted. Also note that the results are unordered.

Answer (score 2):

`Awk` is the tool for this but if you want to be clever with `uniq`:

```
$ column -t file | uniq -w12 -c
      3 Forms.js      /forms/Forms.js       http://www.gumby.com/test.htm  404
      3 Interpret.js  /forms/Interpret1.js  http://www.gumby.com/test.htm  404
```

`column -t` aligns all the columns so we get a fixed width for column one.

---

Or a *hack* if `column` isn't available is to append the first column to end of the line with `awk` and then use `uniq -c -f4` to count unique on the last column and use `awk` again to print the `n-1` fields.

```
$ awk '{print $0, $1}' file | uniq -c -f4 | awk '{$NF=""; NF--; print}'
3 Forms.js /forms/Forms.js http://www.gumby.com/test.htm 404
3 Interpret.js /forms/Interpret1.js http://www.gumby.com/test.htm 404
```

It would be nice if `uniq -f` worked like `-f4,4` or `f1,1`.

---

Or you could use `rev` to reverse the file so `uniq -c -f3` can be done and then `rev` back *(you get the count at the end however and if you don't have `column` you probably don't have `rev`)*

```
$ rev file | uniq -c -f3 | rev
Forms.js /forms/Forms.js http://www.gumby.com/test.htm 404 3      
Interpret.js /forms/Interpret1.js http://www.gumby.com/test.htm 404 3
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't appear that 'column' is supported in cygwin; otherwise, it appears to be what I needed.

Comment: `column` is supported on [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=util-linux%2Futil-linux-2.17.2-1) in the [util-linux](http://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=util-linux%2Futil-linux-2.17.2-1) package :)

Comment: Added a hack if `column` isn't available.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk '!c[$1]++{v[$1]=$0} END{for (i in c) print c[i],v[i]}' file
3 Forms.js     /forms/Forms.js     http://www.gumby.com/test.htm   404
3 Interpret.js     /forms/Interpret1.js    http://www.gumby.com/test.htm   404
```

The above uses the common awk idiom of '!array[$n]++' to tell if a key value ($n where n is $0 or $1 or $4,$5 or ...) has been seen before.

Answer (score 1):

assuming `file.txt` contains your sample input:

```
sort file.txt | awk -f counts.awk file
```

returns:

```
3:Forms.js     /forms/Forms.js     http://www.gumby.com/test.htm   404
3:Interpret.js     /forms/Interpret1.js    http://www.gumby.com/test.htm   404
```

awk script file:

```
cat counts.awk

#  output format is:
#+ TimesFirstFieldIsRepeated:FirstMatchingLineContents

BEGIN {

  plmatch="";
  pline="";
  outline="";
  n=1;

 }

{

 if($1 != plmatch && NR != 1)
  {
   print n ":" outline;
   n=1;
   outline="";
  }

 if($1 == plmatch)
  {
   n+=1;
   if(outline == ""){
     outline=pline;
    }
  }

 plmatch=$1;
 pline=$0;

}

END {
  print n ":" outline;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd just `cut -f 1 | uniq -c`. That won't give you the whole line, but if the lines are differing, printing any line won't make too much sense anyway. Depends on what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You can count the amount of the first field with `cut` but what you want to print after this field ?

```
cat file | cut -d " " -f 1 | uniq -c
```